# How can I add up the cost?

Tags: c#

What I need to do so that I can add every element of `LbCount` to `LbSum` when I click the button.

[image]

When I click button it will cover up my previous number like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(LbCount.Text);
            LbSum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }
```

Comment: If this is solved by one of the answers, please consider accepting that answer by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the names of the text fields, you seem to want to add the number in `LbCount` to `LbSum` when the button is clicked.

`sum` should not start with 0, then. `sum` should start with whatever is in `LbSum`, right?

```
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(LbSum.Text);
sum += Convert.ToInt32(LbCount.Text);
LbSum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please insert `int sum = 0` out of click event Like

```
public int sum = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
  sum += Convert.ToInt32(LbCount.Text);
  LbSum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
}
```

And I suggest use try catch for Convert , Because it'll be Take Exception